# IAB-Clicktag for AMPHTML

Tags: google-ads-api, amp-html, banner, google-web-designer

I just changed my html5 banners to amphtml banners for google ads. They work really well but I can't find a way to add a clicktag which works for google. Could you may help me with this problem?

I've tried the same clicktag as in html5 banners but that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-ad-exit. Have you also tried Google Web Designer (https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/7529856?hl=en). I know it has some level of support for creating amphtml ads. When you say define click tags? Do you mean click tags in the way you would define them in the html5 assets via variable clickTag, so that you dynamically change them in Double Click Campaign Manager/Campaign Manager? If so I don't know if such a thing is supported but it would definitely be in the Campaign manager docs.